# git clone: executing commands in remote machine

Tags: git, clone

I was wondering if there is a way to clone a git repository in an alternative way. I will explain my self.

I have to machines, the problem is that the remote machine is inside a VPN which is not configured in the host machine. Then, if I tip:

```
ssh host@host
(inside host machine) git clone remote@remotedirection
```

I cannot access it and thus clone the repo. I was wondering if there is a way to clone the repository executing the commands from the remote machine (so I can bypass the VPN).

Thanks.

Comment: If the remote machine isn't accessible from the client machine, how do you plan to start the cloning process?

Answer (score 0):

If you remote machine doesn't have the IP or doesn't know how to reach your current machine, just like you mentioned, you will not be able to clone from there.

However, you could push to it if you turn it into a bare repository.

1. Create a bare repository on the remote machine.

```
git --bare init
```

2. In your local machine add the bare repository as you origin.

```
git remote add origin the_remote_git_url
```

Like in this link: https://articles.assembla.com/using-git/how-to-add-a-new-remote-to-your-git-repo

3. Then push your changes to this remote. Let me know if you need more specific.

```
git push  <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

Comment: yes, this was the alternative. I was wondering if I could do something like:  
``` 
git clone repository user@ipaddress 
```